# Redis partitioning on hash key?

Tags: redis, partitioning

After reading redis partitioning document, it seems like redis only support global key partitioning.

I am trying to partition my single hash into different machines. Is there a way to do so?

Example:

```
HSET myhash "foo" 123 // To machine 1
HSET myhash "bar" 456 // To machine 2
...
HGET myhash "foo" // To machine 1
HGET myhash "bar" // To machine 2
...
```

Comment: No, there isn't one currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do it and it will probably never be something like that.